# Counting twice within one query

Tags: mysql, sql

What am I doing wrong? Trying to output two COUNTs and need to Group by Department.

```
SELECT Department, 
       COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS total, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN course LIKE 'AS%' THEN 1 
                ELSE 0 
           END) AS Total_AS
FROM schedule 
GROUP BY Department 
ORDER BY Department ASC
```

Only problem is that `Total_As` is counting `Department` for multiple instances. Just need to count once if `employee(ID)` took at least one training with Course `AS%`. The script is currently counting every single `AS%` taken by `employee(ID)`. Need the `case` part to only count the `employee(ID)` once to indicate that employee took at least one `AS%` training or 0 if they did not attend. `SUM` should not count the employee more than once. Tried to use `MAX` in place of `SUM` but the results only gave 1 or 0 per `Department`. Trying to get output of `Department, Total Employees, # of Employees` in `Department` that have at least 1 `Course Like 'AS%'`.

Output should be:

> Accounting, Total of 20 employees in Department, Total_AS 10.

Using current `SUM`, I get a result for `Total_AS` of 40 because 10 of the `Employees(ID)` took 4 courses each. Just need `Total_AS` to be `COUNT` of `Employees` who took at least 1 Course, which in this case would be 10.

Comment: Fixed title, formatting and improved readability. Please make sure to format your code before posting and always add your table definitions, sample data and expected input.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the SUM to a COUNT(DISTINCT):

```
SELECT Department,
   COUNT(DISTINCT ID) AS total, 
   COUNT(DISTINCT CASE WHEN course LIKE 'AS%' THEN id END) Total_AS 
FROM schedule 
GROUP BY Department 
ORDER BY Department ASC
```