# how to select the count of two different things at once in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, xampp

```
SELECT COUNT(*), 
tanggal as totRits AND COUNT(*), 
total AS tNote  
FROM tblsolar 
WHERE tanggal LIKE '%" & sqlDate & "%' 
AND supir LIKE '%" & cboSupir & "%' 
GROUP BY tanggal
```

How do I `SELECT` the `COUNT` two times?

Comment: you can check it https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30854202/counting-twice-within-one-query

Comment: You can only reasonably count one thing at a time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to get the *total* `COUNT` and a `COUNT` of a *specific column* using different conditions, you can use a subquery like this:

```
SELECT 
  (SELECT 
   COUNT(tanggal) AS totRits
   FROM tblsolar 
   WHERE tanggal LIKE '%sqlDate%' 
   AND supir LIKE '%cboSupir%' 
   GROUP By tanggal) AS totRits,
COUNT(*) AS tNote
FROM tblsolar
```

**Input:**

| tanggal | supir |
| --- | --- |
| sqlDate | cboSupir |
| test | test |
| test | cboSupir |
| test | cboSupir |
| sqlDate | cboSupir |

**Output:**

| totRits | tNote |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 5 |

Adjust your `WHERE` clause conditions as needed for both the main query and subquery.

db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/G7D57WA_).

Answer (score 2):

This `COUNT` function is used to find the number of indexes as returned from the query selected.

Please see the below example-

```
SELECT COUNT(Column1), COUNT(Column2) FROM Table;
```